# What do we know about the set AB if A en B non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ with different conditions on A and B

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

If  $A$ en $B$ non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ and we say that $AB=\{ ab| a \in A $ and $ b \in B \}$.

a)**If $A$ and $B$ are open, $AB$ open?**

I thought this was true. I wanted to proof if there exist a $\delta$ such that
$|a - y/b |< \delta \rightarrow y/b \in A$. Then there is an $\epsilon$ such that $|ab - y |< \delta *b = \epsilon \rightarrow y \in A$ and this proves that $AB$ is open.

b)**If $A$ and $B$ are closed, $AB$ closed?**
I proved this by saying that for $a_n \in A$ with $ a_n \rightarrow a$ and  $b_n \in B $ with $ b_n \rightarrow b$, every convergent sequence $a_nb_n \rightarrow ab$. And then making the calculations
$|a_nb_n -ab|= |a_nb_n - a_nb +a_nb - ab| \leq  a_n|b_n -b| + b|a_n - a|$ and because $A$ is closed it is bounded and then we have $|a_nb_n -ab|< \epsilon$

c)**If $A$ and $B$ are compact, $AB$ compact?**
I wanted to prove this as the last section. I think we can do this because every sequence has a convergent subsequence. So on these subsequences we can apply the method from b) and conclude that these will converge.

However I do not know if my thoughts are correct and I find it strange that it is all possible. Can anybody help me to find places where I might went wrong?

Comment: What does "$A$ en $B$" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) note that $AB=\bigcup_{a\in A} aB$ and verify that $aB=\{ab: b \in B\}$ is open.

Your answer for b) is correct.

c) If $(a_nb_n)$ is  sequence in $AB$ choose a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ of $(a_n)$ which converges to some point $a$ of $A$. Then look at the sequence $(b_{n_k})$ in $B$ and find a further subsequence $(b_{n_{k_j}})$ converging to some point $b$ of $B$.  Now $(a_{n_{k_j}}b_{n_{k_j}})$ converges to $ab \in AB$ and this proves compactness of $AB$.

Comment: For compactness just use that $f(x,y)=xy$ is continuous and $A \times B$ is compact and $AB=f[A \times B]$. IIRC b) is false.